# Best SymmetricDBS architecture for DC to DR replication

Tags: database-replication, symmetricds

We would like to back up a SQL Server cluster at the DC site to another standalone SQL Server at the DR site. We would like to use SymmetricDS and we want all DB objects from the source to be mirrored to the DR (including new tables, triggers and stored procedures). Some tables do not have primary keys.

We would like to know the type of architecture best suited to our needs.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for SymmetricDS would be two nodes that sync with each other.  You could use one node group and link them, like "primary pushes to primary".  By using bi-directional, you can use your mirror database when needed, and it will capture changes to get the other one back in sync when it becomes available.

SymmetricDS will replicate tables and data, but it does not replicate triggers and stored procedures.  Also, the table replication works for most common cases, but misses details like computed columns and defaults that call functions.